# Problem Training an LSTM network in Lasagne for simple task (determining parity of bit sequence)

Tags: classification, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, lstm

I have been trying to gain some familiarity with the Lasagne libraries for machine learning, specifically LSTMs so I set up the following toy problem to determine the parity of a sequence of bits using code from another example.  (I realize that the network is completely overkill for the application).

Whenever I actually start training, the network makes no progress (every attempt is a 50-50 split between the two parity classes).  I have tried varying the hyper-parameters but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

In theory this should be a simple task for the network to learn, so there must be something that I am fundamentally misunderstanding.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Code is below.

```
from __future__ import print_function


import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import lasagne

#Lasagne Seed for Reproducibility
lasagne.random.set_rng(np.random.RandomState(1))

# Sequence Length
SEQ_LENGTH = 7

# Number of units in the two hidden (LSTM) layers
N_HIDDEN = 40

# Optimization learning rate
LEARNING_RATE = .1

# All gradients above this will be clipped
GRAD_CLIP = 100

# How often should we check the output?
PRINT_FREQ = 500

# Number of epochs to train the net
NUM_EPOCHS = 50

# Batch Size
BATCH_SIZE = 100

data_size = 100
def buildNetwork():
    print("Building network ...")

    # First, we build the network, starting with an input layer
    # Recurrent layers expect input of shape
    # (batch size, SEQ_LENGTH, num_features)    
    l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(None, None, 1))

    #Two stacked LSTM layers
    l_forward_1 = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(
        l_in, N_HIDDEN, grad_clipping=GRAD_CLIP,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.tanh)

    l_forward_2 = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(
        l_forward_1, N_HIDDEN, grad_clipping=GRAD_CLIP,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.tanh, only_return_final=True)

    #Slice the output from the LSTM layers to only take the final prediction
    l_forward_slice = lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(l_forward_2, -1, 1)

    l_out = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_forward_2, num_units=2, W = lasagne.init.Normal(), nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)

    # Theano tensor for the targets
    target_values = T.ivector('target_output')

    # lasagne.layers.get_output produces a variable for the output of the net
    network_output = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out)

    # The loss function is calculated as the mean of the (categorical) cross-entropy between the prediction and target.
    cost = T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(network_output,target_values).mean()

    # Retrieve all parameters from the network
    all_params = lasagne.layers.get_all_params(l_out,trainable=True)

    # Compute AdaGrad updates for training
    print("Computing updates ...")
    updates = lasagne.updates.adagrad(cost, all_params, LEARNING_RATE)

    # Theano functions for training and computing cost
    print("Compiling functions ...")
    train = theano.function([l_in.input_var, target_values], cost, updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)
    compute_cost = theano.function([l_in.input_var, target_values], cost, allow_input_downcast=True)

    #Generate a probability distribution
    probs = theano.function([l_in.input_var],network_output,allow_input_downcast=True)

    return (train, compute_cost, probs)

def gen_data(batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, return_target=True):
    #Generate a sequence of 0s and 1s.  Target value is the parity of the sequence
    #i.e. x=0001101 -> y=1  and x=00110011 -> 0 
    x = np.zeros((batch_size,SEQ_LENGTH,1))
    y = np.zeros((batch_size,))

    for n in range(batch_size):
        x[n] = np.random.randint(2, size=(1,SEQ_LENGTH,1))
        if(return_target):
            if (x[n].sum()%2==0):
                y[n] = 0
            else:
                y[n] = 1
    return x, np.array(y,dtype='int32')
def try_it_out(probs):
    #Print a test case during training
    x,y = gen_data(1)
    # Pick the class with highest probability
    ix = np.argmax(probs(x).ravel())
    print("Sequence:",x)
    print("Target:", y)
    print("probs(x)", probs(x).ravel())
    print("Predicted:",ix)


def runIterations(train, compute_cost, probs, num_epochs=NUM_EPOCHS):
    print("Training ...")
    try:
        for it in xrange(data_size * num_epochs / BATCH_SIZE):
            try_it_out(probs) #Run a test

            avg_cost = 0;
            for _ in range(PRINT_FREQ):
                x,y = gen_data()                
                avg_cost += train(x, y)
            print("Epoch {} average loss = {}".format(it*1.0*PRINT_FREQ/data_size*BATCH_SIZE, avg_cost / PRINT_FREQ))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
in_vars = buildNetwork()
(train, compute_cost, probs) = in_vars
runIterations(train, compute_cost, probs)
```

Comment: It isn't clear if this is a code problem (off topic here) or a machine learning conceptual misunderstanding (on topic). Can you clarify? If this isn't about the code, can you add some pseudocode for those who don't read Python? If you want code check, you may want to delete this & post it on the [codereview.SE] SE site instead.

Comment: The code compiles and runs (so from that standpoint, its not a code issue), although it could certainly be a misunderstanding of the underlying library.  In terms of providing more pseudo-code, I tried to add comments to everything to make it more readable.  It's two stacked LSTM layers, which are then sliced (leaving only the last output from each LSTM) which are fed into a softmax layer with two output units for classification.  Let me know how I could edit to be more clear.  If you feel it is off topic, I will be happy to repost it elsewhere, I just thought this would be the best fit.

Comment: Have u been able to resolve the issue? I'm having a similar problem when coding in torch which looks like an algorithmic issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. Take a look at this example for some advice:
https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/recurrent.py

The solution that worked for me was to change the cost function by flattening the output, e.g change

```
cost=T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(network_output,target_values).mean()
```

to something like this:

```
# lasagne.layers.get_output produces a variable for the output of the net
network_output = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out)

# The network output will have shape (n_batch, 1); let's flatten to get a
# 1-dimensional vector of predicted values
predicted_values = network_output.flatten()

# Our cost will be mean-squared error
cost = T.mean((predicted_values - target_values)**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use right init for lstm layers. I use the following initialization:

```
net = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(
    net, 32,
    ingate=lasagne.layers.Gate(
        W_in=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_hid=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_cell=Normal(0.1)),
    forgetgate=lasagne.layers.Gate(
        W_in=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_hid=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_cell=Normal(0.1)),
    cell=lasagne.layers.Gate(
        W_cell=None,
        nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.tanh,
        W_in=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_hid=Orthogonal(gain=1.5)),
    outgate=lasagne.layers.Gate(
        W_in=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_hid=Orthogonal(gain=1.5),
        W_cell=Normal(0.1)),
    backwards=False)
```

try it:)